# Let $f(n)= 10^{n}+3 \times 4^{n+2} +5$

Tags: number-theory, congruences, binomial-theorem

Let $f(n)$= $10^{n}+3*4^{n+2} +5$ ; $ n \in N$. The greatest integer which divides $f(n)$ for all n is:

(a) 27

(b) 9

(c) 3

(d)none of these

Comment: what have you done?

Comment: please update question,i really did not understand

Comment: The answer is 9(as given in my textbook). I could not figure out any method of solving this one because it says for all n.

Comment: three person got $9$so please trust them :D,good  lucks

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586456/common-divisor-of-natural-number-sequence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$10f(n)-f(n+1)=18*4^{n+2}+45=9[2*4^{n+2}+5]$$
and
$$f(1)=207=9*23$$

Comment: great answer,i have got  $9$,but with i think not elegant way

Answer (score 1):

Every common divisor of $f(n+1)$ and $f(n)$ divides $f(n+1)-f(n)=9(10^n+4^{n+2})$.

Comment: is there  such kind of theorem?i am interested

Comment: Euclidian algorithm.

Comment: by the way answer $9$ is coincided  :D

Answer (score 0):

very easy,if we find  one of the answer we are happy,so we will have

$f(n)=10^n+3*4^n*16+5$

right?  so we have  $f(n)=10^n+48*4^n+5$

if $n=0$ then  $f(0)=1+48+5=54$

because  $54/9=6$

clearly   D and c answer is eliminated,could you continue please?

because  $27=9*3$

if we  get answer which would be let say

$f(n)=3*f(0)$

if this system has solution,then  largest is $27$

let us solve following system

$10^n+48*4^n+5=3*54$

or

$10^n+48*4^n-157=0$

we see that $10^n$ is ended always with $0$,while

for $48*4^n$ for different $n$

$n=0$--> we have $48*4^0=1$

$n=1$ we have  $48*4=192$

$n=2$ -->    $48*16=768$

$n=3$  --> $48*64=3072$

$n=4$ -->  $48*256=12288$

for minus it  has not meaning,but for positive do you see pattern?it will never equal any number which is ended with $7$

Comment: @ André Nicolas yest i understood,but from answers  clearly maximum is $27$ what we should get, among the answers i meant,that why  i mentioned that we should find  such $n$ so that $f(n)=3*f(0)$

Comment: aa wait,you mean for all $n$ so that what is minimum?

Comment: We want to find the largest number that divides our expression for **all** $n$. Take $n=1$. Then the function value is not divisible by $27$.

Comment: and result must be integer?

Comment: i understood,i just tried to help him,thanks anyway

Comment: Yes. Since I wrote the comment, a complete answer by N.S. has appeared.